# How to secure the APIGateway generated URL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, aws-lambda, backend, aws-api-gateway

I have a serverless backend that operates with **APIGateway** and **Lambda**. Here is my architecture:
[image: Architecture]

Currently, anyone with my APIGateway's URL can query or mutate the data. How do I protect the URL, so that only the client(react app) can access it. So, here is my concern, anyone can open the **network** tab in chrome console and get my APIGateway's URL and can use it using curl or postman. I want to prevent that.

Solutions I had in my mind:

1. Set up a CORS, so that only the **origin** can access it. But, I have a different lambda that invokes this URL. So, CORS wont work out.

I am sure there are some methods with the **APIGateway** itself. I am not getting right search term to get it from AWS documentation. I would also like to know what are the best practices to prevent accessing the backend URL apart from the Client(React App)

### Update after @Ashan answer:

Thank you @Ashan for the answer. In my case, I use Auth0, so custom authoriser should work for me. I just came across this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n4hsWVXCuVI, which pretty much explains all the authorization and authentication possible with APIGateway. I am aware that authentication is possible either by Cognito/Auth0, but I have some simple websites, that has form, whose backend is handled by APIGateway. I can prevent the abuse from scraping bots using captcha, but once the attacker has got the URL, header and request parameters, he can invoke that million times. One thing, we can do is having an **API-Key**, but it is a static string with no expiration. Once the headers are with him, he can abuse it. So, any idea, how to prevent this in APIGateway. If not any other service apart from AWS that I can look for? Would be glad, If I get an answer for this.

Comment: Does the User need to login on the React App? If so, you can use Cognito User Pool as an auth strategy on API Gateway side, then the request without a valid token will be blocked as expected.

Comment: what do you mean by different lambda..?

Comment: @KaHouIeong nice point. I use Auth0, maybe I should search something with that. Is there any other easy approach to solve this like adding an api key?

Comment: @naveenkerati This URL will not only invoked by the client(react app), but also another Lambda, which invokes this URL. So, I mentioned this, just to tell that CORS will not work in my case

Comment: Auth0 has tutorials for securing API Gateway: https://auth0.com/docs/integrations/aws-api-gateway

Comment: @MarkB Nice. I think it should work. Any idea for websites where we do not use Auth0, Coginto. I have some simple forms that sends data to database through APIGateway. As these URLs and request data can be easily taken from network tab in chrome, I would like to know how to prevent it.

Comment: @LakshmanDiwaakar The security token should be generated when the user logins to the app. Even the user tries to capture the request from network tab, the token will be expired in a short period of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently API Gateway does not support private urls, so it will be publicly available.

To restrict access you need to use a authorizer to authenticate and authorize the request using IAM policies. There are two options available at the moment.

- IAM authorizer
- [Custom](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html) authorizer

If your authentication flow can directly (AWS STS, IAM user access keys or roles) or indirectly(Using AWS Cognito Userpools or any other SSO provider) can get temporary security credentials, then you can use IAM authorizer. From API Gateway side no code involved and its a matter of selecting the IAM check box for each API Gateway resource. You can use the API Gateway SDKs to invoke API Gateway requests where the SDK will handle the heavy liftings in setting up authentication headers.

If you use your own authentication mechanism, then you can write a seperate Lambda function to validate the tokens. This Lambda function name can be specified at API Gateway with the http hearder name to access the custom token to verify the requests.

To control API usage by authorized consumers, using API Key is the only way native to AWS at the moment.

Since you are using S3 for the react app hosting, you can further reduce the attack surface by using [AWS WAF](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/) and CloudFront infront your application stack. The API Key can be added to CloudFront headers to forward to your APIGateway origin and since CloudFront and APIGateway communication happens using SSL, its nearly impossible for someone to find the API key. Using AWS WAF you can limit malicious access for common attacks. This includes rate based blocking to limit someone from repeatedly invoking the API.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have modified the question a little bit, check my updated question. I would be glad, If you give me your opinions on this

Comment: Nice. I was thinking WAF is only for protecting DDOS attacks to the website  as such. I am interested in your concept of sending api keys from cloudfront to api gateway url. Can you explain on that more or share me a link? Coz am not able to get the proper search term for searching the transmission of api key from cloudfront to api gateway

Comment: You can add x-api-key:{api_key} header to CloudFront Origin. Check the following link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/forward-custom-headers.html. Also make sure you whitelist headers and not send Host header to APIGateway behaviors.

Comment: Thank you ashan, I will check it out.

Comment: Sorry @Ashan, for asking too many questions. I think, the link is more for the front-end. When a browser asks for the webpage, first it goes to cloud-front and if there is a miss, it goes to S3. The link helps us to set up custom headers for the above case. But I cant understand your concept of using cloudFront's custom header and passing it to Backend (APIGateway).

Comment: No worries! If you edit the API Gateway Origin (Not the behavior) in CloudFront, there is a place to add permenent headers forward to APIGateway. You can add the APIKey header mentioned above there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148186/discussion-between-lakshman-diwaakar-and-ashan).